# inter process communication in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, communication, semaphore

I have a cloud process which downloads certain files to the cloud.
How can I let my mother process know about success or failure to do some clean up work if required?

Should I be using semaphores?

Oh an something else, my cloud process never ends, so I can't exercise a .join()

Comment: Did you try using Signals? IPC?

Comment: @Brent See update, I don't have any semaphore code yet... that was just a thought... another way of doing it, is, I could just write to a file from which my mother process would read but that seems a little awkward so to say...

Comment: @Thomas no, I have not research either of tehm yet..., Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the mother process spawns the child process(es), the child process can exit with a success/failure code.  The code determines if cleanup is required.  Then the mother process spawns a new child process.  See [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for info.